# I want to merge 2 tables together using a formula, so it presents like "a Gantt chart"

Tags: excel

Thank you very much for reading this.

Say I have some lumber costs. And I can say "It'll take $3000", split this way between task 4 through 6 and I can tell it will be $X per month from months 4 to 8"

I can take this small example and eventually come to the bottom distribution at the end of the screenshot, where the costs zigzag down, drawing down the first task by that month then when it runs out, go to the next task. Same with the month. That way, they're all "merged" together by both metrics.

[image: An example of the 2 tables "merging"]

This requires both tables to have the same sum for Material 1 to work. It feels like there's a clever combination of formulas that can take any 2 table columns as input and do this "Gantt charting" zigzag, but I don't know how.

I want to layer in multiple materials to the same table, but that's an addition I can likely solve for. But just the initial logic of it put into formula instructions is escaping me. Any help would be appreciated. If it has to be VBA so be it, maybe it's too tough since it's storing information like the remaining balance of the task/month.

I tried looking up if this was already asked somewhere first, but I don't know if what I want is described well in just a header.

I also tried some vlookups that minus the sum of the columns to the left of it, but that doesn't really work, like this:

```
=AQ6-VLOOKUP(AT28,AP15:AQ23,2,FALSE)-SUM(AQ32:AS32)
```

Comment: This is a difficult question from a mathematical perspective. In your example you chose `500, 500, 200, 0, 0; 0, 0; 300, 500, 0; 0, 0, 0, 500, 500` but that is not the only solution, e.g. `200, 400, 50, 50, 500; 100, 0, 50, 650, 0; 200, 100, 400, 300, 0` is another possible "zig-zag" (and there are many more). Which one should the formula return?

Comment: Would you explain the logic for the result of the third table for each row and cell with values. I guess you are representing just Material 1. Thanks!

Comment: I would say it should be biased towards using all available dollars in the first cell if possible, as early in the task and month. The alternative zigzag you mention seems to be "fat" and these tasks are sequential , where they dont happen concurrently very often. Multiple solutions could exist but it can be assumed to be the one where dollars are allocated as much as possible as early as possible, not dragged out.

Comment: As for the logic, the third table does just pull from only material 1. I figure if a solution can be determined from the 1 column, it can be scaled up to as many columns as needed by just adding the formula for material 2 the same way.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first two tables are data and the third one is what you want to populate programmatically. But your example uses only one material and it is not clear the result in the third table. If you want, change the image by putting another one with two materials. This way it will be clear exactly what you want and as they say: "A picture is worth a thousand words"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Karsten Winkelmann, I was intrigued by your question and decided to write some code so that with one click you can get results from as many materials as you want. Of course, I modified the tables by replacing the columns with lines because I thought that way you would be able to add other materials more easily. What I thought is that there is no "zigzag" but a horizontal expansion of each task (within the months) until its amount is used up. So I made an algorithm and I am posting it. I will be happy if you avoid "copy-paste". If you are satisfied with the way the problem is solved but want the tables in their original form, let me know and I will try to adjust it.

**COPY ALL THE CODE IN THE SHEET'S MODULE**
TASKS is the sheet in my example, i don't use tables (only optical)
but these ranges:

```vb
    R_A=TASKS!$B$2:$I$13   
    R_B=TASKS!$B$18:$I$29
    R_C=TASKS!$B$36:$I$43
'--------------------------------------------'

    Option Explicit
        
    Private Sub BTN_CALCULATE_Click()
       Call calculateTable_TaskMonth
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub calculateTable_TaskMonth()
       Dim mnths As Long, tsks As Long, mtrls As Long, c As Long
       Dim mt As Long, ts As Long, tskMoney As Long, firstMonth As Long
       Dim ra As Range, rb As Range, rc As Range, perMonth As Variant
       
       Set ra = Me.Range("R_A")       
       tsks = ra.Columns.CountLarge
       mtrls = ra.rows.CountLarge

       Set rb = Me.Range("R_B")
       mnths = rb.Columns.CountLarge

       Set rc = Me.Range("R_C")
       rc.ClearContents
       
       'FOR EVERY MATERIAL (lines)
       For mt = 1 To mtrls
          'THE LISTBOX HAS THE MATERIALS IN THE SAME ORDER AS IN TABLES
          'IF MATERIAL NOT SELECTED JUMP TO NEXT MATERIAL
          If Me.ListBox1.Selected(mt - 1) = False Then GoTo Lnext_Material

          'read in array the materials money per month
          perMonth = rowRngTo1Darr(rb.rows(mt))
          'find the first month with money
          For firstMonth = 1 To mnths
             If perMonth(firstMonth) > 0 Then Exit For
          Next
          
          'for every task in material 
          For ts = 1 To tsks
             tskMoney = ra(mt, ts).Value2
             If tskMoney > 0 Then
                'if task has money τηεν divide them into months...
                For c = firstMonth To mnths
                   'if the month has money for the task...
                   If tskMoney <= perMonth(c) Then
                      With rc(ts, c)
                         .Value2 = .Value2 + tskMoney
                         'reduce month's money
                         perMonth(c) = perMonth(c) - tskMoney
                      End With
                      'goto next task
                      Exit For
                   Else
                      With rc(ts, c)
                         .Value2 = .Value2 + perMonth(c)
                         'reduce tskMoney 
                         tskMoney = tskMoney - perMonth(c)
                         perMonth(c) = 0
                         'money for month c finish => move firstmonth to next
                         'so star from this month on the next task.
                         firstMonth = c + 1      'firstMonth + 1
                      End With
                   End If
                Next
             End If
          Next
    Lnext_Material:
       Next
    End Sub

    'helper function
    'HORIZONTIAL RANGE (ONE ROW) TO ONE DIMENTIONAL ARRAY
    Function rowRngTo1Darr(r As Range, Optional hdrRows As Long = 0) As Variant
       rowRngTo1Darr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(IIf(hdrRows = 0, r, r.Offset(0, hdrRows).Resize(1, r.Columns.CountLarge - hdrRows))))
    End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this looks really good! It'll take some time for me to work this coding into the full design I'm thinking of. I'm glad Stack Overflow's experts aren't being mean to me about this, I've heard stories you don't like newbies.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. I did a very crap version of this. Hopefully this helps others.

I did it in a series of tables since trying to get this all in one formula is nightmarish.

[image: The full series of tables]

So first, vlookup anything in that task and put the value in the rows, call it the "only task box"

Secondly, do the same for month, put it in the column. "The only month box"

You now take the minimum value of both the above tables, and it gives you a "box". This is the defined regions of your material costs, it can't have any costs outside the "box". Add subtotals to the box by vlookup to the data tables.

Make a "yes box" which is just a Yes/no boolean of whether the value is 0 or not.

Finally, we get to the answer box.

=IF(BF28=1,MIN(BF17,BF$21-SUM(BF$34:BF37),($BK17-SUM($BC38:BE38))),0)

So if the "yes box" is true (else 0), return the minimum value of:
A) the full amount of "the box" (the max value)
B) the total sum of the rows minus sum of all prior rows
C) the total sum of the columns minus sum of all prior columns.

And it works! Gives the answer.

Now I need to make 24 of these table boxes and then sum them all up.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Better version, [image: Condensed]

The 2 data tables above, and now only 1 intermediary table for the logic.

1. The table pulls the subtotal amounts in the month and task column/rows.
2. as for the data chart: =MIN(VLOOKUP($B15,$B$2:$C$10,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G$12,$E$2:$F$10,2,FALSE))

Which combines the 3 tables above into 1, just take the minimum of the raw data being looked up from the tables. Which if it's 0, is just 0.

Next table, pulls if greater than 0. So bypasses the "yes box". Similar logic to just pull the minimum of the 3 options, the cell value, the row total minus all prior row amounts, or column total minus all prior column amounts.
=IF(E14>0,MIN(E14,E$21-SUM(E$24:E24),($K14-SUM($C25:D25))),0)

3 major hangups:

1. The logic isn't smart enough to know if it's at the first row or column so add a blank row and column to compensate.
2. Needs some setup on $ formatting to make sure new projects are usable.
3. This doesn't do concurrent tasks. At all. Adjust your task timelines accordingly.

On a more general note, this may not be useful for all purposes. My thoughts for doing so are this:
Lets say you're doing revenue.

1. You have how much money you can charge per item. Data table 1.
2. You have how much money you need revenue per month for cashflow. Data table 2.
   Adding them together gets you a timeline you need to keep to get that money by these chargeable items.
   Since timelines aren't theoretical, you need to compare to what an actual timeline is. In this example, if Task 3 takes 3 months, that's not good. Adjust one of the tables. You're undercharging for it or expecting too much cashflow.

Comment: After all, all this work is for one material? and will you repeat it for every other material?

Comment: Copy paste is a wonderful tool. Do it 24 times and just change the column in the 2 data tables, then add all 24 tables in sequence. Hide it, make it pretty.

Comment: Hi! @Karsten Winkelmann, did you see my answer?